# QSerialPort readyRead() signal not emited

Tags: qt

```
connect(serialScanner->serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), serialScanner,
SLOT(handleReadyRead()));
```

Why is it than with the respective serial port opened, my code never gets into the connected function that is handleReadyRead()?

The code below is my alternative implementation within the class constructor, so as everything has the same scope.

```
 if (scanConnectedSerialDevices()){
        serialPort = new QSerialPort();
        portPath = serialPortName;
        serialPort->setPortName(portPath);
        qDebug()<<serialPort->portName();
        serialPort->setBaudRate(this->serialPortBaudeRate);
        connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(handleReadyRead()));        
        connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(handleBytesWritten(qint64)));
        serialPort.openPort(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

**edit: Changing the Device, thus the Driver due to the scanner being from a different manufacturer my code works just fine??????**

Comment: put all related codes here . There are several possible causes for this. for example it is important to know whether two objects: serialport and serialscanner are in same thread or in different threads.

Comment: And use new Qt5 signal/slot connection syntax!

Comment: The other alternatives that I have tried, involve connection of signals and slots within serialScanner class constructor, so everything has the same scope. Neither did this work...Putty though connects succesfully with my scanner
Why use new connection syntax, I know I have to but why